# Joomla! mod_article_category wrong links

Tags: php, url, joomla, module

I'm in trouble here.

I've been seeking the web for an anwser but I didn't find one **detailed enought** for my **noob level** in joomla! (2.5 here)

I use the module `mod_articles_category` to display a list of articles sample which should link to the entire article.

I have created a menu (called `Articles` with a link `article`) bound to the `articles` category. (I heard it was necessary)

*So when I click on a link in my sample article list what happend ?*

- I land on the same page with this url `mysite.com/index.php/article/1-a`
- The page don't have any style, all paths to the css/js files are wrong

*What do I want when the link is clicked ?*

- I would like to land on a page that display the entire article (like in wordpress you see?), but I only have an `index.php` file (and styles and xml of course) in my template folder. How can I do that ?

Thanks a lot !

**- EDIT -**

Hum finally I think that the problem comes from my $this->baseurl wich changes to the name of my menu.

Example:

If I call my menu `Popopo`  and its link `domdomdidom` then the url will be `mysite/index.php/domdomdidom/1-a` and my $this->baseurl `/domdomdidom` wich cause all my paths to crash.

Any Idea of how to fix it ?

My paths are made this way:

`<?php echo $this->baseurl; ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template; ?>/css/reset.css`

Thx again

---

### /* ANSWER */

The problem came from the **url rewriting configuration (SEF)**. I **switched it off** and I have my styles back ;) (but the article isn't displaying, I still get the list.. it's another problem this one is ok)

Also for better URL change htacces.txt to .htaccess and check the second Url Rewritting (you can even reactivate SEF).

Well sorry for all this noise.

Comment: What are the paths that are generated?

Comment: mysite.com/article/template/mytpl/css/styles.css Strange

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Create a menu in your menu manager with name like `Blog or Articles`

Select menu type as any of the following based on your requirement

```
Archived Articles
Single Article
List All Categories
Category Blog
Category List
Featured Articles
Create Article
```

now check the site and click the menu.

Hope its helped ..

Comment: Ok, in menu manager I've create a menu called ´Articles´ within it a link called ´article´ with the type ´List All Categories´, but it changes nothing. Should I assign a module to my menu or something?

Comment: Choose the menu type from the select option and set any of the above options it will automatically adds the proper link for your selections and will appear in the front end, No need of any other modules.

Comment: Ok maybe my menu is well configured, and the problem is elsewhere. Why do my paths to css are `mysite.com/article/template/mytpl/css/styles.css` while the links point to `mysite.com/index.php/articles/3-article-name`. Thx for your help